# Check if no results with mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is a way in mysql to check if the query produces some results and if no do execute query.
 Example:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=2) IF NO RESULT (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=4)
```

**EDIT**

I need only one query, basically first I check if there a result with a param (ex status=0) if there is no result I would like to execute the same query with the param changed to status=2.
Hope it can help

**MORE EDIT**
Basically I have a table with operatorators and departments and another one with all the users, first I check if there is an available operator in the first table and it's not on holiday, if there is no result I will lselect and admin from the second table, but only if there is no operator availbable

**MORE MORE EDIT**
This query check if there is an operator available but it doesn't select the admin

```
query = "SELECT b.id  
        FROM ".$SupportUserTable." b
        INNER JOIN ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." a
            ON b.id=a.user_id
        WHERE a.department_id=? AND b.holiday='0' AND a.user_id!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
        ORDER BY b.assigned_tickets,b.solved_tickets ASC LIMIT 1";
```

**Lastest Solution** 
This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it works, I'm open to improvments to avoid the execution of two queries:

```
$query = "SELECT *
                FROM(
                        (SELECT b.id  
                            FROM ".$SupportUserTable." b
                            INNER JOIN ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." a
                                ON b.id=a.user_id
                            WHERE a.department_id=? AND b.holiday='0' AND a.user_id!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
                            ORDER BY b.assigned_tickets,b.solved_tickets ASC LIMIT 1)
                    UNION
                        (SELECT id  
                        FROM ".$SupportUserTable."
                        WHERE  status='2' AND id!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
                        ORDER BY assigned_tickets,solved_tickets ASC LIMIT 1)
                    ) tab
                    LIMIT 1
            ";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175217/sql-server-if-not-exists-usage

Comment: Sometimes this kind of question points to poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry Tables design? Because this is the best I can think, the user can be assigned to multiple department, so I decided to create a different table (user and user per department), the first keep track of the user status(operator, user or admin) and holiday and the second  of the user associated department, I tought that add the administrator to the the second table isn't advantageous, because if I add a new department I have also to add every administrator to it. if you have any suggestion I'll be glad to listen

Comment: So a given user might be (simultaneously) an `operator` in one department and an `administrator` in another?

Comment: Sorry, an user can be an operator(on multiple department) or an administrator (only global)

Comment: My logic is: I don't know if the site has got only one person(admin) or multiple operator+admin, so I applied this structure, however the admin can choose to move the ticket to another operator or admin

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (2,4) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: @Dheed: I would advise against using `IF` in this query.  Try to adapt using the technique I have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
Select IF(
(SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE id=2), (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=2),(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=4))
```

Comment: `IF()` can't return multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from
(SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id in (2,4)
LIMIT 1)t
order by t.id
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to get both results

Comment: Now there is a syntax error (no `FROM` clause in the outer query); and the subquery uses `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, which will still yield indeterminate results.