# How to check if a value exists in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following code which I am trying to use to check if a value is already stored inside the db.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM [Clock] WHERE [clockIn] ='12/03/2016'
             AND UserName = 'ROSE'
)
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('CLOCK IS TRUE NOTHING MORE TO DO',16 ,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
ELSE
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM [Clock] WHERE [clockIn] ='12/03/2016'
    AND UserName = 'ROSE'
)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Clock] ([clockIn], [UserName])
        VALUES(GetDate(), 'Rose')
    END
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is working as it always seems to insert a new row into the db and I am puzzled. I have used the following as an example [SQL Server IF NOT EXISTS Usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175217/sql-server-if-not-exists-usage) and also [SQL Server 2008 - IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update) as reference.

Comment: Is your ClockIn data type date? If it's datetime then you'll have also hours, minutes etc. and your comparison won't match. Using country specific date formats is a bad idea, use YYYYMMDD instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JamesZ. My fields are of Datatype DATE. If I convert this to datatype of datetimw will this help to resolve my issue?

Comment: You are adding rows with `getdate` value but trying to locate them with constant date filter. Also your date format is not locale-safe. Try '20160312'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems ok to me - but the `IF NOT EXISTS` in the `ELSE` case is superfluous - you already **checked** and got back the fact that that value does not exist - so there's really no need to check **again**.

However: you're checking for existence of a row with a **fixed** date specified in a string literal - that'll work *today*, but not anymore tomorrow. I'd recommend to first get the current date into a variable, and then use that variable both for the checking and the possible insert.

```
-- store today's date in a variable  
DECLARE @Today DATE = SYSDATETIME();

-- check if that row already exists in table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Clock] 
           WHERE [clockIn] = @Today AND UserName = 'ROSE')
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('CLOCK IS TRUE NOTHING MORE TO DO',16 ,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Clock] ([clockIn], [UserName])
    VALUES(@Today, 'Rose')
END
```

As a side note: I'd recommend to use the **ISO-8601** format when specifying dates as string literals - `YYYYMMDD`. That format will work with any language and/or regional settings in your (and anybody else's) SQL Server, while any other format can be dependent on the settings and might not work all the time!