# SQL - Insert Where Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I have what I thought to be a completely trivial query - insert values into a table if a value with a matching ID does not exist:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID, Description)
   VALUES (1, 'Internal')
   WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Contact_Categories] WHERE Contact_Category_ID = 1)
END
```

I get an error around the where statement. Why? How do I accomplish my goal?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a row exists, otherwise insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639854/check-if-a-row-exists-otherwise-insert)

Comment: `BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID, Description)
   SELECT 1, 'Internal' FROM [dbo].[Contact_Categories] WHERE Contact_Category_ID <> 1)
END`

Comment: @PaulVarghese What it it doesn't exist yet? Then there is no `Contact_Category_ID = 1`;

Comment: @VSO Check TZHX answer...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem comes from `WHERE` being valid for UPDATE/SELECT but INSERT just doesn’t understand what it means.

But you can get around this. Change your code to be like:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID, Description)
   SELECT 1, 'Internal'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Contact_Categories] WHERE Contact_Category_ID = 1)
END
```

Comment: That's quite elegant, better than the IF construct alternative

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace your query with:

```
BEGIN
     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Contact_Categories] WHERE Contact_Category_ID = 1)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID,Description) VALUES (1, 'Internal')
END
```

Comment: This query must be inside a transaction to prevent race conditions, otherwise someone might insert a row between the time that the table was checked and the insertion of the row.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is by using a unique index/constraint:

```
create unique index unq_Contact_Categories_Category_Id on Contact_Categories(Contact_Category_ID);
```

The database will then guarantee the uniqueness for the column.  This prevents race conditions.

You can catch this using `try`/`catch`:

```
BEGIN TRY
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID, Description)
       SELECT 1, 'Internal';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'Ooops';  -- you can even raise an error if you like.
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not an If statement?

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(select * from [dbo].[Contact_Categories] WHERE Contact_Category_ID = 1)
  begin
    insert into [dbo].[Contact_Categories] (Contact_Category_ID, Description)
    values (1, 'Internal')
  end
```

This has the advantage of not doing anything if the value exists. Similar to answer provided here: [SQL Server IF NOT EXISTS Usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175217/sql-server-if-not-exists-usage)

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact_Categories](Contact_Category_ID, Description)
   VALUES (1, 'Internal')
   WHERE 1 NOT IN ( SELECT Contact_Category_ID FROM [dbo].[Contact_Categories])
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, this is my solution.

```
insert into Contact_Categories (Contact_Category_ID, Description)
   select 1, 'Internal' 
where not exists 
   (select * from Contact_Categories where Contact_Category_ID = 1 and Description = 'Internal');
```