# How can I do 'insert if not exists' in Ms sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to move data from  table1  to table2 (both the tables have same structure)with  condition of comparing their emaild (unquie)in both the tables...if the data of emaild exits in table 2 I should not load that data otherwise I have to insert the record in table 2..these two tables are in two different databases of same sql server instance... Could you please provide me with the syntax.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Insert Where Not Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779223/sql-insert-where-not-exists)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT db2.dbo.table2(key, other cols)
  SELECT key, other cols
  FROM db1.dbo.table1 AS t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM db2.dbo.table2 AS t2
      WHERE t2.key = t1.key
  );
```

You can double-check you're getting the right rows by commenting out the first line.

Here's an example with a procedure on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a3fb69a47fe3c8f28e9ef0c1d6953634).

Comment: Can you please show me how to write these in stored procedure

Comment: @VinithKumar What do you mean? You asked a generic question, how do I do this type of insert. This is how you do it. If you need to do this in a stored procedure, ok, wrap a `CREATE PROCEDURE` around it. If you need to learn how to create a procedure, there are many tutorials all over the Internet.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Bertrand

Comment: How does the table gets iterated to the second row if we compare only 1st row from the table

Comment: @VinithKumar I'm really not understanding your question. Where are we only comparing a single row?